# Python class gets imported multiple times in pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, python-import, python-importlib

My assert fails with the following message:

```
AssertionError: assert False  
where False = isinstance(<foo.bar.MyClass object at ...>, <class 'foo.bar.MyClass'>)
```

When I decided to print some data about the class of the object and the expected class, I was confused because they were the same, except that they had differend ids:

```
print(actual_class.__module__, actual_class.__name__, actual_class.__qualname__, id(actual_class))
>>> foo.bar, MyClass, MyClass, 94568362217456
print(expected_class.__module__, expected_class.__name__, expected_class.__qualname__, id(expected_class))
>>> foo.bar, MyClass, MyClass, 94568348237280
```

`sys.path` contains no duplicate paths, so I ruled it out

However, there are fixtures (in other test modules) that instantiate a class and call one of its methods that calls `importlib.import_module` on a list of modules. I decided to add some logging into this method and run the tests again. Turns out there may be different copies of the same module. Just look at this:

```
module=<module 'foo.bar' from '/file/system/foo/bar/__init__.py'> id(module)=140678353806656 os.getpid()=30940
module=<module 'foo.bar' from '/file/system/foo/bar/__init__.py'> id(module)=140678282268320 os.getpid()=30940
module=<module 'foo.bar' from '/file/system/foo/bar/__init__.py'> id(module)=140678267882208 os.getpid()=30940
module=<module 'foo.bar' from '/file/system/foo/bar/__init__.py'> id(module)=140678283736544 os.getpid()=30940
module=<module 'foo.bar' from '/file/system/foo/bar/__init__.py'> id(module)=140678263743168 os.getpid()=30940
```

It's easy to see that this module gets imported multiple times during the lifetime of the same process

Here's the most important snippet of code from this method:

```
def import_module(self, module):
    importpath = ".".join([self._package, module])
    module = importlib.import_module(importpath)
    self._modules[importpath] = module
```

Q1: How is that even possible? I thought that Python prevented multiple imports of the same module
Q2: How do I fix this?

P.S. I'm using Python 3.8

Comment: does something call `reload(...)` somewhere?

Comment: @AnthonySottile no, there are no explicit calls to `reload` that I could find

Comment: maybe put something like `if hasattr(sys, 'hax'): raise AssertionError('where am I?'); sys.hax = 1` in the module to debug where the extra imports are coming from?

Comment: @AnthonySottile thanks for the suggestion as a way to track across all of `sys` for a double-import!  I used that as a basis to derive a more detailed variant for fixing a problem I'd been having and to answer a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73639070/2738164

Answer (score -1):

In C/C++, there is a traditional way to prevent multiple imported:

```
#ifndef MODULE_H
#define MODULE_H
// code
#else
#endif
```

You can also use it in Python:

```
if ‘imported’ not in globals():
    imported = True
    # code
```

The `imported` variable means that this module has been imported. If it is undefined, it means that the module has not been imported, then the class will be defined in global. Otherwise, the module has been imported, the class won’t be defined again.