# Does pytest import modules twice?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a helper class in a test module that has a class-level member in which I cache already-created members of the class (sql dumps of database configurations composed in fixtures, so that I don't have to derive the data again for multiple tests).

It starts:

```
class SqlDump:
    FIXUP = re.compile(r"^(\s*CREATE SEQUENCE[^;]*)AS INTEGER([^;]*);",
                       flags=re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
    PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'test_data/sql_dumps/{script}.sql')
    all = {}

    def __init__(self, script):
        self.__class__.all[script] = self
        self.script = script
        self.content = self.load()
```

If I place a breakpoint on the initialization of this member `all`, using it outside pytest, it is initialized only once.

But when I run pytest, the line that initializes the member is executed twice.  This results in some values being lost.

Is there ever any reason a class-level member should be initialized twice?  Why is pytest doing this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a year old now, but in case it helps someone else:

There was a very similar issue in my case, where a module was getting rerun over and over from pytest.  This particular module (SQLAlchemy) is highly sensitive to reinitializations, resulting in an opaque error of `Multiple classes found for path in the registry of this declarative base`.  This did not occur during normal runs of the platform - only when pytest was run.

Here's how the project was structured:

```
ProjectName
│   __init__.py
│   script_outside_modules.py
│
└───actual_module
    │   __init__.py
    │   pytest.ini
    │   some_code.py
    │
    └───some_subfolder
    │   │   __init__.py
    │   │   a_file_to_test.py
    │
    └───tests
        │   __init__.py
        │   test_suite.py
```

All imports were absolute from the `actual_module` root, e.g. `actual_module.some_code`.

If you want to triage exactly how `sys` sees your module imports, and whether the same module was imported such that it's seen as two different modules, try using the following code in a module which you believe could be getting double-imported, outside of any encapsulation (e.g. above `class SqlDump` in your example):

```
import sys
import traceback
print(f"{__file__} imported by module {__name__}, in sys.modules as {sys.modules[__name__]}")
try:
    if hasattr(sys, 'double_import'):
        raise AssertionError(f"{__file__} was double-imported!")
except Exception as e:
    traceback.print_exc()
    raise e
sys.double_import = 1
```

Reading what it's registered as in `sys.modules` should help you identify where the disconnect is happening and whether you have odd module import scenarios playing out.

After hours of investigating possible causes and logging, I found that the extra import was due to the `__init__.py` at the root of the project, inside `ProjectName` in this case.  The code above helped to illustrate this, where  `sys.modules` showed an module for `actual_module.some_code` during preparation phases, but then showed another module at `ProjectName.actual_module.some_code` within the tests themselves.

This seems to be because pytest will identify a root separately from whatever is defined in imports and prepend it when running tests (though that's just a working hypothesis).  Deleting `ProjectName/__init__.py` resolved my issue.